# Avoid Date Numbering format in excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have been writing an excel using `C#` and found this issue while i pick a HTML field and write the contents into excel.

Actual Content : `5     8     3`

Excel writes : `05/08/2018`

Code:

```
worksheet.Cells[iRow, 5].SetValue(string.Format("{0}", columnValue));
```

Is there any format that i have to set something like this? I use the below code for `DateFormat` but for a different Cell.

```
CellSelection cellSelection = workbook.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[iRow, 1];
cellSelection.SetFormat(new CellValueFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

How can i make the excel write the same value ('5   8   3') ?

**Note:**
Also tried removing the above DateFormat code and the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

To format a cell to "Text" you can use the Format Provider `"@"`.

In this case the value can be retained by,

```
worksheet.Cells[iRow, 5].SetFormat(new CellValueFormat("@"));
```

Try adding the code before you write into the cell and this should work.